# How to format an integer with zero padding in Julia?

Tags: string, julia, string-formatting

If I have an Integer, say 123, how can I get a zero-padded string of it to a certain length?

For example, 123 with 6 wide would become "000123", but 1234567 to 6 wide would be "1234567".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
julia> string(123, pad=6)
"000123"
```

Answer (score 3):

Printf is included with Julia and is more flexible, but @MarcMush's answer is cleaner.

```
julia> using Printf

julia> s = @sprintf("%6.6i",i)
"000123"
```

There is also [Formatting.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl) for even more options.

Answer (score 3):

There are `lpad` and `rpad` functions.

```
julia> lpad(123, 6, '0')
"000123"

julia> lpad(1234567, 6, '0')
"1234567"
```